# How do I place two div containers in the same row, side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have two div contentainers, each of them has header and paragraph inside them.
Now I want to place the container in the same row,so that they can stay side by side, with the equal margin from the top.

This is what I have tried. The problem with this one, as you can see is that the second container doesn't sit in the same line, it seems it has longer margin than the first one.

HTML:

```
    <div id="gallery">
<div id="gallery-text-1">

<p id="gallery-text-quote-1" style="font-family:Century Gothic; color:#006600"><b>Header-1</b></p>

<p id="gallery-paragraph-1">
paragraph1
</p>
    </div>
<br />
<div id="gallery-text-2">
<p id="gallery-text-quote-2" style="font-family:Century Gothic; color:#006600"><b>Header-2</b></p><br /> 

<p id="gallery-paragraph-2">
paragraph2
</p>
</div>
    </div>
```

.CSS:

```
    #gallery-text-1{
    float:left;
}

#gallery-text-2{
  float:left;  

}
```

See demo: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tag3nb3z/)

Comment: I would prefer to use `display:inline-block;` over `float:left` IMHO. Also, the `<br />` tag is forcing a new line, so removing that would allow them to display side by side if rom allows.

Comment: Remove the <br> tag. also I'd suggest using a grid system like zurb foundation or getfractional.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<br>` tags and that fixes your problem.

Comment: jaunt, thank u very much for your answer. It solves my problem though. But now the only remaining problem is there is no space between two containers, they are closly attached with each other.

Comment: Then you could use margin or padding to separate them by a defined amount, or change `#gallery-text-2{float:left;}` to `#gallery-text-2{float:right;}` for them to be separated across the page.

Answer (score 0):

apply some width to both the div's and then use float left property on them

```
#gallery-text-1{
    width:45%;
    float:left;
  }
#gallery-text-2{
  width:45%;
  float:left;  
}
```

try this